# Stripe retrieve subscription gets blank response

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to implement stripe and Im all good until I try and retrieve a subscription

I send my secret and sub id and get a 200 ok and a blank response

Am I doing anything wrong?

```
//Create a new stripe instance
        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
            config('stripekeys.secret')
        );
        //Retrieve stripe record
        $stripe->subscriptions->retrieve(
            'sub_IV0LDLuFIfKvce'
        );

        //Build return data
        $data = [
            'status' => 200,
            'data' => $stripe
        ];
        //Return data
        return response($data);
```

I followed the docs here https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve?lang=php

Comment: Try once by hard coding the secret key in the code itself instead of grabbing from config and see if it works fine to ensure nothing is wrong from stripe api end.

Comment: So I managed to fix by setting the second stripe call to a variable

Answer (score 0):

```
        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
            config('stripekeys.secret')
        );
        //Retrieve stripe record
        $return = $stripe->subscriptions->retrieve(
            'sub_IV0LDLuFIfKvce'
        );

        //Build return data
        $data = [
            'status' => 200,
            'data' => $return
        ];
        //Return data
        return response($return);
```

This works perfectly